# Monitor frequency is only 30hz in 4K when it could do 60hz

Tags: gpu, xorg, gnome, 4k-resolution

I run an up-to-date Archlinux on a Dell Ultrasharp U3219Q 32" monitor, at a 3840x2160 resolution.
My graphic card is a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti with 4GB of memory, I run the proprietary blob driver version 515.57 on X11, with GNOME.
The monitor is connected with the DisplayPort port, with a DP1.4 cable.

[The documentation of the monitor](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_display_projector/esuprt_display/dell-u3219q-monitor_user%27s-guide_en-us.pdf), on page 15, shows that the maximum frequency that it should be capable of at this resolution is 60hz. [This website (not nvidia's website)](https://www.gpuzoo.com/GPU-NVIDIA/GeForce_GTX_1050_Ti.html) shows that the GPU should be able to handle 7680 x 4320 @60 Hz. However the GNOME settings menu, and xrandr, consider the maximum is 30hz:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep VGA -A1
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] [10de:1c82] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:85d1]

$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm
   3840x2160     29.98*+
   2560x1440     59.95
   2048x1280     59.96
   2048x1080     24.00
   1920x1200     59.88
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    23.98
   1600x1200     60.00
   1600x900      60.00
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1280x720      59.94    50.00
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       59.94
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

How can I fix this and get 60hz?

Comment: [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/scth0h/another_no_4k_60hz_on_linux/) any help? This is a bit beyond me but I hope it helps. Also I assume the cable you're using can support 4k@60Hz right?

Comment: Indeed the cable is DP1.4.